# How can I use a Google Apps Script to add multiple Google Docs to a Google Drive folder?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a list of Google Document URLs (about 700 of them) and need to add them to a Google Folder so that they are all in one space because currently they are owned by hundreds of different users.

I've seen a few postings on how to do the inverse of this: Generate a list of URLs from the contents of a folder. This has been helpful, but it seems this task is much more difficult.

This is what I've tried, and it doesn't seem to be working:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openById('1sQGds0kyeO66ZiMiJlsKkHPcqjySPy5q0dWShc2irts'),
docFile = DriveApp.getFileById( doc.getId() );
DriveApp.getFolderById('0B7yp85g7j5ZHbVlEUmNGX2w0M1k').addFile( docFile );
DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(docFile);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this? What links are you referring?

Comment: [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) is a good way to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't error check and may timeout... but it is a start. 
You would add the fileIds in Column A.

```js
function makeCopyFromId() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 700;   // Last row to process.
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"); 
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var ssId = row[0];  
    Logger.log(ssId);   // check the log to see if they all complete-
  
     var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(ssId).makeCopy("",destFolder))  //copies each file.     
  }}
```

Comment: This looks like it combines data inside a spreadsheet. Thanks for the reply, but it's not what I'm looking for. Given a list of document ids, I need to add them all to a provided folder id.

Comment: this copies each spreadsheet that is listed by id in colA  to yourdrive

Comment: I see! It makes a copy of each one to the folder. It worked. Thank you!

Comment: yeah just be careful check the logs- do it in batches?  it may time out after 20 or 50 or whatever...

Comment: For some reason it's not copying in the specific folder. Is there a way to call out the folder it needs to be copied to by id.